# Creating an array from scratch while code is running

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, dataset

I am trying to create a list via array like this:

```
private Application[] GetApps()
{
DataSet ds = new Dataset();
string query = "query";
ds = GetData(query);

var appList = new Application[ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count];

for(var i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
                DataRow item = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i];

                appList[i].Name = item["Name"].ToString();
                appList[i].Confidentiality = int.Parse(item["Conf"].ToString());
                appList[i].Id = item["ID"].ToString();
}
return appList;
}
```

I keep getting an object null error and I know I have to be missing something completely obvious that I'm just not seeing. Do I need to declare the new array in some other way?

Comment: Which line do you get the exception?

Comment: Check whether NAME, Conf, ID are null in your database

Comment: Does GetData actually return a dataset with a table in it? Breakpoint and make sure - you aren't handling ds==null so it would throw an exception if it were.

Comment: Also, while the string fields will convert dbnull to null, the int.parse will puke on that if it is. You should make sure Conf is never null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you create `appList`, you are only creating the array itself. .NET does not automatically populate the array with Application objects for you to manipulate. You need to create a new Application object, and set the properties on that object, then you can assign the object to the array.

There are multiple `Application` classes withing the .NET framework, none of which seem to match your code, so the below example will simply assume that `Application` is a custom type of your own design.

```
for(var i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DataRow item = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i];

    Appliction app = new Application();
    app.Name = item["Name"].ToString();
    app.Confidentiality = int.Parse(item["Conf"].ToString());
    app.Id = item["ID"].ToString();
    appList[i] = app
}
```

As an aside, note that you can replace `i <= x - 1` with `i < x` and the behavior is exactly the same.

Finally, you should introduce checks for all of your accessors if there is a chance that they could return null. For example, if `item["Name"]` returns null, then calling `item["Name"].ToString()` is equivelant to calling `null.ToString()`, which will also result in a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: Thank you! You were correct that Application is my own class.